# What is the purpose of a ramdisk when fadvise exists?

Tags: hard-drive, cache, io, ramdisk

My understanding is that [`fadvise`](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~plonka/fadvise/) will tell the system that the indicated files should be stored in the file system cache (RAM).

What is the purpose of mounting a directory in a ramdisk when you can just `fadvise --willneed` the directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us read [the manual page for the underlying library call](http://linux.die.net/man/2/posix_fadvise):

> Programs can use posix_fadvise() to announce an intention to access file data in a specific pattern in the future, thus allowing the kernel to perform appropriate optimizations.
>
> The *advice* applies to a (not necessarily existent) region starting at *offset* and extending for *len* bytes (or until the end of the file if *len* is 0) within the file referred to by *fd*. **The *advice* is not binding; it merely constitutes an expectation on behalf of the application.**

(Emphasis added.)

Everything on a RAM disk is guaranteed to be in RAM, by design (though tmpfs can be swapped out). But fadvise is merely advisory; the kernel is not required to preload the data into RAM, nor to always keep it in RAM.